# How to force a CSS grid container to take the whole width when there is an overflow?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

(Given the snippet below)

When there is no overflow on the X axis (i.e. no scrollbar on the X axis), the grid container takes all the width available.

When there is overflow on the X axis, the grid container doesn't have the same width as its child, so when one scroll on the right, one can notice that [the background color of the grid container isn't present on the whole width](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YIHrs.png).

How can one make the grid container take the whole width?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:  "header"
                        "content";
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: grey;
}

.header {
  grid-area: header;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: green;
}

.content {
  grid-area: content;
}

.content-child {
  width: 600px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="header">
    Header Header Header
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="content-child">
      Content Content Content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Instead of `display: grid`, use `display: inline-grid` with `min-width: 100%`. https://jsfiddle.net/ew0z1p52/